# regex to delete whitespace in csv-file with quotes to separate text?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, grep

I'm new to programming and regex and read Mastering Regular Expression, but I can't find an answer to how to get rid of tabs, newlines and strange non-word or non-digit characters (icons and strange non-western linebreaks(?) mostly) within the text column of my tsv-file. It's utf-8 formatted and in Swedish language.

It looks like this:

```
"from_user","month","full_text"
"bellaboo",4,"RT @BodilMalmsten: \"om man klarar av att föra ett bestick till munnen eller      behöver hjälp på toaletten\"
Have a heart, borgarrådet
Have a hea,RT @BodilMalmsten: Borgarrådet om riktlinjerna \"om man klarar av att föra ett   bestick till munnen eller behöver hjälp på toaletten\"
Hjälp
1   min dröm
2   allas önskningar
3   viljan att segra
H,RT @BodilMalmsten: Klarar du av att föra ett bestick till munnen eller behöver hjälp på  toaletten?
http://t.co/fcvcf0U2dW"
```

Can anyone please help me so I get on with the text analysis I'm really about to do with this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with `python-3.x` here is a Python 3.x answer.

I think the problem you have is that a CSV reader will get upset with all the newlines inside the third column.  This program strips out all the extra newlines and normalizes all the white space (words are separated by a single space).

I'm using a "verbose" Python pattern with comments to make it clear how it matches the columns.  The tricky one is the third one, which can contain newlines.  It just matches anything until a terminating double-quote is seen.

I'm not sure exactly how you want to clean the string; the pattern I gave just replaces all "control characters" (ASCII `0x01` through `0x1f` inclusive, plus the ASCII `DEL` character `0x7f`) with spaces.  Then the whitespace normalization cleans up any extra spaces.

```
import re
import sys

_, infile, outfile = sys.argv

s_pat_row = r'''
    "([^"]+)"  # match column; this is group 1
    \s*,\s*  # match separating comma and any optional white space
    (\S+)  # match column; this is group 2
    \s*,\s*  # match separating comma and any optional white space
    "((?:\\"|[^"])*)"  # match string data that can include escaped quotes
'''
pat_row = re.compile(s_pat_row, re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)

s_pat_clean = r'''[\x01-\x1f\x7f]'''
pat_clean = re.compile(s_pat_clean)

row_template = '"{}",{},"{}"\n'

with open(infile, "rt") as inf, open(outfile, "wt") as outf:
    data = inf.read()
    for m in re.finditer(pat_row, data):
        row = m.groups()
        cleaned = re.sub(pat_clean, ' ', row[2])
        words = cleaned.split()
        cleaned = ' '.join(words)
        outrow = row_template.format(row[0], row[1], cleaned)
        outf.write(outrow)
```

You can edit the pattern specified in `s_pat_clean` to clean any characters you need cleaned.

To use this, save it in a file called `cleaner.py` and put your input in a file called `data.txt` and then run:

```
python3 cleaner.py data.txt cleaned.txt
```

Results are saved in the output file `cleaned.txt`.

The result of running this on the example you provided:

```
"from_user","month","full_text"
"bellaboo",4,"RT @BodilMalmsten: \"om man klarar av att föra ett bestick till munnen eller behöver hjälp på toaletten\"Have a heart, borgarrådet Have a hea,RT @BodilMalmsten: Borgarrådet om riktlinjerna \"om man klarar av att föra ett bestick till munnen eller behöver hjälp på toaletten\" Hjälp 1 min dröm 2 allas önskningar 3 viljan att segra H,RT @BodilMalmsten: Klarar du av att föra ett bestick till munnen eller behöver hjälp på toaletten? http://t.co/fcvcf0U2dW"
```

Now a CSV reader should have no trouble parsing the file.

EDIT: Re-ran the program with correct input and replaced output example with result of running on correct input.  When the input has accents, they are correctly passed through as you can see above.

Comment: idk if your script actually works but +1 for offering a python solution. I just added a php solution that seems to work fine for me, based on my conversation with OP.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove everything except "regular" (english) "word" chars, you can do this (php example, since you didn't specify language. The pattern itself is `[^\w ]` or if your language doesn't support shorthand char class, you can use `[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]`):

`$string = preg_replace('~[^\w ]~','',$string);`

if you want to make it utf-8 mode since you mentioned Swedish language (not very clear if you wanted to remove that or preserve it) you can use the `u` modifier:

`$string = preg_replace('~[^\w ]~u','',$string);`

again, this is php example; you didn't specify what language you are using..

IOW the actual regex pattern would be

`[^\w ]`

or

`[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]`

and you will need to enable utf-8 support in whatever language or environment if you want to preserve Swedish chars.

**edit:** I also threw in a regular space because you probably want to preserve that too!

**edit 2:** actually the newline chars are a whole other can of worms to deal with. Since they put your data on separate lines, it's going to hose your attempts to use built-in functions for reading the (csv) file.  What you may be able to do to rectify this is before the above, first open the file as a whole and run a replace for `\r?\n(?=[^"])` to "" (empty string) . The php version would be

`$string = preg_replace('~\r?\n(?=[^"])~','',$string);`

The idea is to strip all of the new lines, except the ones that have a quote after it, under the assumption that your columns are wrapped in quotes and to preserve the actual rows in the file

**edit 3:** this is how i would do it in php. I wish I knew enough python to give you the python version but I don't, so maybe you can figure out how to run the php version (it's really not that hard..) or get someone to translate it for you.

First run this script:

```
<?php
/* 
 STEP 1:
 run this on original data initially, to strip all newlines, except for the 
 ones thatare supposed to be there to start a new row 
*/
// get the data from the original data file
$file = file_get_contents('data.csv');
// strip out newline chars that are not followed by a quote
$file = preg_replace('~\r?\n(?=[^"])~','',$file);
// write the data to a new file to preserve original data
file_put_contents('data2.csv',$file);
?>
```

then run this script:

```
/*
 STEP 2:
 run this to strip out non-word chars and extra spaces, preserving swedish chars
*/
// set php to parse using Swedish settings (e.g. utf-8)
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Swedish");
// open the new file that's scrubbed of bad newlines
$handle = fopen("data2.csv", "r");
// also let's open another file to put in final scrubbed data in
$handle2 = fopen("data3.csv", "w");
// for each row in the file.. (fgetcsv puts the columns into an array $data) 
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  // for each column in the current row...
  array_walk($data,function(&$value) {
    // first let's strip all non-word chars except spaces 
    $value = preg_replace('~[^\w ]~','',$value);
    // then let's consolodate multiple spaces into a single space
    $value = preg_replace('~ +~',' ',$value);
  });
  // now let's write the scrubbed row to the new file. we're going to use fwrite
  // instead of fputcsv because fputcsv will not always wrap the columns
  // in quotes. So we're going to ensure that each column has quote wrappers, 
  // same as original. This isn't a problem for most csv parsers but just in 
  // case you're rolling your own.. 
  fwrite($handle2,'"'.implode('","',$data).'"'.PHP_EOL);
}
// finally, let's close the files. 'data3.csv' contains the final scrubbed data
fclose($handle);
fclose($handle2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What language are you using? The only one I'm fairly familiar with by now is Python. I was looking for a "plain" regex pattern that I can try out in e.g. grep.

Comment: @mattiasostmar okay well these patterns should work for you. Just note that `~` isn't part of the actual pattern; it's php specific, acts as pattern delimiter.

Comment: @mattiasostmar okay i made some more edits to clarify some things and also throw in normal spaces..

Comment: I can't seem to make it work, despite your thorough answer. It only matches the commas in between quotes:
[screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/PqyLKqlu)
Can you see if I make any mistake, or if it isn't supposed to work that way in the program regexr?

Comment: @mattiasostmar i added another edit about newlines.. also, from your link it looks like you have quotes around the pattern, which aren't supposed to be there

Comment: The pattern you wrote in your second edit doesn't match anything at all for me: [screenshot from regexr](http://screencast.com/t/yF3q5l9LVxuW). Clearly I must be doing something wrong here. Can you show me a grep version or something like regexr for how you make it work?

Comment: OK, removed the quotes, but it doesn't match the linebreak after "hjälp" strangely enough: [without quotes](http://screencast.com/t/JFzoxWNNreD)

Comment: @mattiasostmar http://www.myregextester.com/?r=9ce3d2a7 the "source text" shows the original text, the "highlighted matches" shows what it's matching, and the "results" shows the results, showing that only the newlines that aren't followed by a quote are removed. And then from there, you can run the first regex on the column. Normally you would use a function to grab each column value individually, like in php there is fgetcsv which parses the csv row

Comment: Ah, thanks - almost there! Only thing is that it cuts away the first character on the eight last lines, which are the same that shows on the [highlighted matches tab](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=9ce3d2a7#highlighttab). Is that because something in the pattern?

Comment: aah oops, here's a new link: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=8c7cb01a using lookahead to check but not actually capture and replace that non-quote char

Comment: @mattiasostmar I wrote a php script version of what i'd do, see edit. I know you mentioned only knowing python atm but i don't know python well enough to do it in that language, but hopefully it will help you move forward nonetheless