# Delete whitespace characters in quoted columns in tab-separated file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I had a similar text file and got great help to solve it, but I have to realize that I'm too new to programming in general and regex in particular to modify the great Python script below  written by [steveha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166949/steveha) for a [Similar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387359/regex-to-delete-whitespace-in-csv-file-with-quotes-to-separate-text).

**EDIT:** I want to get rid of tabs, newlines and other characters than "normal" words, numbers, exclamation marks, question marks, dots - in order to get a clean CSV and from there do text analysis.

```
import re
import sys

_, infile, outfile = sys.argv

s_pat_row = r'''
    "([^"]+)"  # match column; this is group 1
    \s*,\s*  # match separating comma and any optional white space
    (\S+)  # match column; this is group 2
    \s*,\s*  # match separating comma and any optional white space
    "((?:\\"|[^"])*)"  # match string data that can include escaped quotes
'''
pat_row = re.compile(s_pat_row, re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)

s_pat_clean = r'''[\x01-\x1f\x7f]'''
pat_clean = re.compile(s_pat_clean)

row_template = '"{}",{},"{}"\n'

with open(infile, "rt") as inf, open(outfile, "wt") as outf:
    data = inf.read()
    for m in re.finditer(pat_row, data):
        row = m.groups()
        cleaned = re.sub(pat_clean, ' ', row[2])
        words = cleaned.split()
        cleaned = ' '.join(words)
        outrow = row_template.format(row[0], row[1], cleaned)
        outf.write(outrow)
```

I can't figure out how to modify it to match this file, where there is \t separating the columns and text instead of a number in the second column. My objective is to have the cleaned text ready for content analysis, but I seem to have years of learning before I get to that point where I'm familiar... ;-)

Could anyone help me modify it so it works on the data file below?

```
"from_user" "to_user"   "full_text"
"_________erik_"    "systersandra gigantarmadillo kuttersmycket NULL NULL"  "\"men du...? är du bi?\". \"näeh. Tyvärr\" #fikarum,Alla vi barn i bullerbyn goes #swecrime. #fjällbackamorden,Ny mobil och en väckare som ringer 0540. #fail,När jag måste välja, \"äta kakan eller ha den kvar\", så carpe diar jag kakan på sekunden. #mums,Låter RT @bobhansson: Om pessimisterna lever 7 år kortare är det ju inte alls konstigt att dom är det.

http://t.co/a1t5ht4l2h,Finskjortan på tork:     Check! Dags att leta fram gå-bort skorna..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV file uses tabs for delimiters rather than commas, then in `s_pat_row` you should replace the `,` characters with `\t`. Also, the second field in your sample text file includes spaces, so the `(\S+)` pattern in `s_pat_row` will not match it. You could try this instead:

```
s_pat_row = r'''
    "([^"]+)"          # match column; this is group 1
    \s*\t\s*           # match separating tab and any optional white space
    ([^\t]+)           # match a string of non-tab chars; this is group 2
    \s*\t\s*           # match separating tab and any optional white space
    "((?:\\"|[^"])*)"  # match string data that can include escaped quotes
'''
```

That may be sufficient to solve your immediate problem.

Comment: When I run your s_pat_row I end up with a file only containing the first line: "from_user" "to_user"   "full_text". 

Does that work for you?

I'll try with changing your script part also...

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your sample data file. Is that really supposed to be a single line with embedded newlines?

Comment: Yes, theres's an \n on the empty line and there's a \t between "tork!" and "Check!" on the last line.

Comment: I see, this is thornier than I realized. Using the `csv` module isn't going to help you when the "fields" include newline characters. The immediate problem I think is that the second field of your file includes spaces, so `(\S+)` will not match it. I've updated the answer with a pattern that seems to work for me on your sample text, at least to parse the CSV fields.

Comment: Strange, I must be mixing something up: a just end up with an empty file now. Here's the script I run now: https://gist.github.com/mattiasostmar/7862242

Comment: I run it with:
$> python3 cleaner_tabs.py data.txt cleaned.txt
where cleaner_tabs.py is the file I linked to above.

Comment: That appears to be pretty much exactly what I did to reproduce your script, and the output looks fine to me. Are you quite sure that the input file is separated with tabs?

Comment: Ahh! You're right - it had changed automagically to spaces - but now it works! You're great! :-)

Comment: Yay!  I'm glad to help. :-)